# R data.table: check which column is not NA and get the value of this column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table similar to this one:

```
      gnr  konf_prot  konf_kath       konf_andere  konf_ohne
   1: 1136        NA  #F16913         NA           NA
   2: 1150        NA  #F16913         NA           NA
   3: 2890   #9E9AC8       NA         NA           NA
   4: 4401        NA  #FEE6CE         NA           NA
   5: 2427        NA       NA         #FD8D3C      NA
```

It has a ID column (gnr) and some columns containing color codes. In each row, only one column has a color value, all the others are NA.

What I want is a new data.table with just two columns: `gnr` and `colorcode`. Colorcode contains the color value that appears in one of the other columns within this row.
So I need a function that checks which column is not NA and then assigns this color value to the new column colorcode.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `melt` to convert to 'long' format.  Here, we are assuming the "gnr" as `unique` and the OP already mentioned that there will be a single non-NA element, this approach would give the new dataset with the two columns.

```
melt(setDT(dt), id.var = "gnr", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "colorVal")[, 
                    variable:= NULL][]
```

---

A `base R` approach would be using `max.col`

```
setDF(dt)
data.frame(dt[1], ColorVal =dt[-1][cbind(1:nrow(dt), max.col(!is.na(dt[-1]), "first"))])
```